# Tsql, returning rows with identical column values

Tags: t-sql

Given an example table 'Users', which has an int column named 'UserID' (and some arbitrary number of other columns), what is the best way to select all rows from which UserID appears more than once?

So far I've come up with

```
select * from Users where UserID in 
(select UserID from Users group by UserID having COUNT(UserID) > 1)
```

This seems like quite an innefficient way to do this though, is there a better way?

Comment: In what sense unefficent? Do you have millions of users or what? I think your query is just fine; if you have milions of rows, then of course UserID must be indexed for this type of query.

Comment: I intuitively feel there must be some way to do this without using a subquery. Of course I could be totally wrong.

Comment: More to the point: why would userID 'ever' appear more than once in a Users table?

Comment: although you can rewrite the query using `EXISTS()` or a `JOIN` the resulting query plan will most likely be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could use this approach:

```
;WITH UsersNumbered AS (
  SELECT
    UserID,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID)
  FROM Users
)
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
  INNER JOIN UsersNumbered n ON u.UserID = n.UserID AND n.rownum = 2
```

Provided there exists a non-clustered index on `UserID`, this yields a slightly worse execution plan than your approach. To make it better (actually, same as yours), you'll need to use... a subquery, however counter-intuitive it may seem:

```
;WITH UsersNumbered AS (
  SELECT
    UserID,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID)
  FROM Users
)
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UsersNumbered n
  WHERE u.UserID = n.UserID AND n.rownum = 2
);
```

In case of a clustered index on `UserID` all three solutions give the same plan.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the same thing but evaluate the performance and it would likely be faster/more efficient. Of course there should be an index on this UserID column.

```
select u.*
from Users u
join (select UserID,count(UserID) as CUserID from Users group by UserID) u1 on u1.UserID = u.UserID
where CUserID > 1
```